# How can I tell Django to execute all queries using 10MB statement mem?

Tags: sql, django, performance, postgresql

I'm using Django with postgresql database.

I'm having very limited access for database configuration and can't alter `postgresql.conf`.

However if I want to execute all queries through django with specified `statement_mem` settings say 10MB.

I tried using `cursor.execute("set statement_mem='10MB'")` - it is working but how can I write it in generic way - so each every API calls go using by this setting?

Comment: It looks like the MySQLdb driver *does* support this using [the `init_command` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#creating-your-tables), however, the PostgreSQL driver doesn't according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the cursor in your own class that executes `cursor.execute("set statement_mem='10MB'")` on every call but otherwise mimics the cursor class. You could "monkeypatch" the real cursor class too, but this could be confusing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I got an another clue is: execute cursor.execute in wsgi file only.